# How do I convince customers about the importance of code refactoring?

Tags: qa-role, code-review

I affirm working on a software testing project for a customer. Due to a tight budget, I am the only one writing code here.

I am thinking of performing code refactoring at the end of this project, but this will extend my staying for around 5 working days.

The customer I am working for knows little about coding, let alone code refactoring.

Anyone has any experience about how to convince a customer about how important code refactoring is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a mail to the customer stating the importance of code refactoring:

1. Highlight that the refactoring will really help to increase
   the maintainability of the code (it's like an investment therefore even if it
   might not help you in near future, it will really come to the play in
   after 7 or more years later when new developer team will taking the
   code and start maintaining the project).
2. Also it will definitely lower the technical debt.
3. Sometimes it will increase the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Explain them that refactoring is an important part of software development with the advantages for the customer.

1. While it doesn’t make a noticeable change to the software from the end user perspective, it helps to **reduce costs of future development**.
2. Regular refactoring of your code will make your life as a developer easier, (even in the future developments, when development crew has changed) **and benefit your clients by saving them time and money in the long run**.

https://www.netguru.co/blog/refactoring-why read this link, it will more helpful you to explain them the why it's need Refactoring .